# Google maps pointer does not drag correctly

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google

I am using the chrome browser with google maps on ubuntu 16.04. When I attempt to click and drag the map the pointer does not become a hand but remains and a pointer and I cannot drag. If I perform this action while using firefox it works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, try to clear the browser’s cache and cookies.

Then toggle the Hardware Acceleration setting on Google Chrome.Go to **Chrome Menu** > Click **Settings** > Click **Show Advanced Settings** > Under **System** uncheck/check Us

Finally, try using an incognito mode.

Comment: Only switching to incognito mode provides a solution, why incognito mode? And I don't always use this mode.